# calculate time complexity of nested for loops

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o

I am having trouble calculating the time complexity for these for loops:

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    countOne++;
    for(int j=i/2; j<len; j++){
        countTwo++;
        for(int k=i/2; k<len; k++){
            countThree++;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to calculate the time complexity for the 2 inner-most loops.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "calculate the running time"?

Comment: I think you want to calculate complexity `Big O` ? right ?

Comment: yes, Big O running time. I would like to know the running time of each line, specifically the 2 inner loops. For example, I believe the first for loop runs n+1 times.

Comment: @AdrienneKeck I think the term you are looking for is [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), not running time (which is most commonly referred to as [run time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase))). It's impossible to calculate the run time of your code since this depends on an infinitely large number of additional factors.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a Big Oh question. But you should specify that in the future.

- `countOne` is incremented `len` times.
- For every `i`, `countTwo` is incremented `len-i/2` times. `i` goes from 0 to `len-1`, so `countTwo` is incremented between `len/2` and `len` (or O(len)) times per `i`, or O(len<sup>2</sup>) in total.
- similar story for `countThree`, it's incremented O(len<sup>3</sup>) times.

Therefore the entire algorithm is O(len<sup>3</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

You proceed methodically with Sigma notation:

[image]